# QT Quick: invalid property name <<width,visible....>>

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I had started to learn qt Qml programming, I'm using the latest version of Qt Creator and have a problem with my qt quick projects. Whenever I am creating a new qt quick project I'm getting the issue inside my Qml file that the generated properties name is incorrect. But when checking the connection of the modules, it is observed that everything is OK.

Maybe someone faced such problems or there are some options for solving this problem?

```
Window {
    visible: true                              invalid property name <<visible>>
    width: 640                                 invalid property name <<width>>
    height: 480                                invalid property name <<height>>
    title: qsTr("Hello World")                 invalid property name <<title>>
}
```

Comment: Which `import`'s do you have on top of the file?

Comment: import QtQuick 2.15

Comment: @NativeNova Can you please insert your full qml file here and full error message from QtCreator?

Comment: you need to `import QtQuick.Window`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-window-qmlmodule.html

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#details) first, before asking a question. That should be the first step if you as you say "_had started to learn qt Qml programming_". And the documentation clearly says: "To use this type, you will need to import the module with the following line: import QtQuick.Window 2.2"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope this will help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to suppress the err msg:

1. Add "imports QtQuick.Controls 2.xx"

I don't comment on the exact versions, bcoz my install'n may be diff from yours.

2. Change the QML Object From:

Window{...}

To:

Window{ ApplicationWindow{...width, ...height ...} }.

i.e. to enclose an AppWin{} inside Win

These are obviously Qt Project Generation Bugs, bcoz the problem appears right on proj creation, BEFORE any user modifications.

To be honest I DON'T bother to explore the diff btwn AppWin{} vs Win{}, as long as any one of them can be used to build my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `// @disable-check M16` before each property:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    // @disable-check M16
    width: 640
    // @disable-check M16
    height: 480
    // @disable-check M16
    visible: true
    // @disable-check M16
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```